# Is there any way to add the tag of a person I have fake banned?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm in the process of making a command that fake bans people, but looks like it bans them for real, just to freak people out and to troll them. It's quite convincing right now, but I want to add the tag of the user I have fake-banned in the command. Here is what I have so far:

```
@client.command(help = 'bans people trol')
async def ban(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = 'no reason lma-'  
    await ctx.send(f'Banned **{user.name}**. Reason: {reason}')
```

I used to have `user.mention` in the place of `user.name`, but that's a dead giveaway for the fake ban, so I changed the command to `user.name`, but this still only fetches and sends the username of the person. If I banned a person named `@Kid#1111`, the command would read `"Banned **Kid**. Reason: no reason lma-"`

How would I add the tag in? I'm assuming it's just a matter of changing the `user.name` to something else, but I can't find what that would be in documentation.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is your expected output `Kid#1111` instead of `Kid`?

Comment: Yeah, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discord.Member.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.discriminator) to get the tag of the member. So you can put the name and the discriminator together.

```py
@client.command(help = 'bans people trol')
async def ban(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = 'no reason lma-'  
    await ctx.send(f'Banned **{f'{user.name}#{user.discriminator}'}**. Reason: {reason}')
```

Comment: Ah, so user.discriminator retrieves the tag of the user I'm fake banning. Thanks for the help!